# Search and replace unicode character

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, unicode

I'm using this [search and replace](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-replacetext/tree/master/docs) jQuery script . 
I'm trying to put every character in a span but it doesn't work with unicode characters.

```
$("body").children().andSelf().contents().each(function(){
    if (this.nodeType == 3) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.replaceWith($this.text().replace(/(\w)/g, "<span>$&</span>"));
    }
});
```

Should I change the node type ? by what ?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "unicode characters"?

Comment: (Note: [`andSelf`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/#entry-longdesc) as of jQuery version 1.8. You should use [`addBack`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack) instead, which is equivalent, but I suppose they preferred the name.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace \w (only word caracters) by "." (all caracters)

```
$("body").children().andSelf().contents().each(function(){
    if (this.nodeType == 3) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.replaceWith($this.text().replace(/(.)/g, "<span>$&</span>"));
    }
})
```

Comment: This will fail horribly with  [bananas](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f34c/index.htm). `"".replace(/(.)/g, "<span>$&</span>")` results in the broken string `"<span>\uD83C</span><span>\uDF4C</span>"`. (it is broken enough that SO would not let me post the whole thing unescaped as a comment; I had to write the escapes manually)

Answer (score 0):

The RegEx pattern for matching "any character" is `.` not `\w` (that only matches 'word characters'—in most JS flavors the alphanumeric characters, and the underscore `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`). Note `.` also matches space characters. To only match and replace non-space characters, you can use `\S`.

For a full-listing of the JS RegEx syntax, see [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Special_Characters).

To replace any and all characters, make your regex `/./g`

```
$("body").children().andSelf().contents().each(function(){
    if (this.nodeType == 3) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.replaceWith($this.text().replace(/(.)/g, "<span>$&</span>"));
    }
});
```