# In HTML replace unicode character &#9776; with X on click

Tags: jquery, html, unicode

I am using the unicode character for menu icons `&#9776;` and like to replace it with the `x` character on click.

The HTML document encoding is UFT-8. `<meta charset="utf-8">`

There is also some text, `Menu` (followed by a space), before the unicode character and that I do not want to change since the font-size of that is adjusted dynamically with [FlowType.js](http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/), meaning if I change the whole lot the replaced font-size is not the same making the design quite ugly.

[Here is the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m2uk78oa/).

This is what I have tried but somehow it is not catching the character in quotation marks and I am useless at regex.

HTML

```
<div id="menu-button" class="menu-button" >
    <p id="menu-button-link">Menu &#9776;</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#menu-button {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 80px;
}

#menu-button-link {
  width : 120px;
  height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

jQuery

```
// https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js
// JS on DOM ready

$menuButtonLink = $('#menu-button-link');

$(document).on('click', '#menu-button', function(event) {

  $menuButtonLink.text(function () {

    $(this).text().replace("&#9776;", "X");
    alert('unicode character replaced');

  });

});
```

Is there a good site that can teach me to catch the proper characters with regex or can this also be done with jQuery but without regex somehow?

I looked at this question [Search and replace unicode character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501534/search-and-replace-unicode-character) but could not get it working.

Comment: You could just use .text("") to replace Menu ☰ with Menu X. `$(this).text("Menu X");`

Comment: Tried that and since I am using FlowType.js for the font-size of `Menu `, when I replace the whole thing the font-size given by CSS is applied but the FlowType.js change to this font-size is not and this makes the inserted `Menu ` appear much smaller what makes the whole thing look pretty ugly. Wish it would work in this case. Since I am calling FlowType.js inside Enquire.js for a particular media query it gets quite entangled and I don't want to call FlowType and Enquire each time the user clicks on a menu item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to use a regular expression, as you can use the unescaped character directly in the expression, like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#menu-button', function(event) {
    $menuButtonLink.text(function(i, t) {
        return t.replace(/☰/, "X");
    });
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/m2uk78oa/2/)

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I see you are supplying parameters to the function, what does the `i` and `t` do please? Beginner here. Also can I generally use the unescaped character for such a task, or does this work in this particular case exclusively? Last thing, some time ago I was at this jQuery regex site but forgot the link, do you know of any good regex testing grounds?

Comment: `i` is the index of the element in the matched set, `t` is the current text value. See http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function for more info. You have to be careful of the page encoding when using the unescaped character. Regex is much more tolerant so in this case it becomes a non-issue. The regex testing site I use is http://regexr.com

Comment: No problem, glad to help.